# How to get the length of page scrolled vertically and add it to something?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a half visible (using max-height) div that contains some text, I want to add the length of page scrolled to the max-height. I used

```
var topScroll = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
```

But its returning `60` instead of `60px` or `50` instead of `50 px` that's making my max height `60xxx px` `50xxx px`.

My JavaScript code:

```
var topScroll  = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
topScroll = parseInt(topScroll);
$('#' + topScroll ).append("px");
console.log(""+topScroll);

var elem = document.getElementById("content");
var articleHeight = window.getComputedStyle(elem, null).getPropertyValue("max-height");

$(window).scroll(function (){
    var x  = topScroll + articleHeight ;
    $('.article-on').css('max-height',x);
    console.log(""+x);
});
```

Comment: `var topScroll = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;` will never return `50px` or `60px` but, as you wrote, it returns `60` and `50` which is the number of pixels without the `px` ending. If you want to assign this number to a CSS property, you can just simply append the `px` ending to the given number like: `x = x+"px"`.

Comment: What Mark has suggested is correct. You can append 'px'. But I believe `topScroll` should be updated in `scroll` function

Comment: I have included my append code , is it not correct? @MarkFrankli

Comment: Well, run the code and see what happens. Since I can only see your JavaScript code I cannot decide whether is correct or not. First, you should include other parts of the file like CSS and HTML.